# Linked linked destructor raises segmentation fault

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, destructor, singly-linked-list

I am trying to delete a linked list using the destructor.

But this code is giving a segmentation fault:

```
~Node()
{
    Node *current = this ;
    Node *previous = NULL;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
        delete previous;
        previous = NULL;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are in effect calling `delete this`, which calls `~Node()` destructor, which calls `delete this`, which ... . It doesn't make any sense to delete a node in the destructor of that same node - if the node is being destructed, someone has already deleted it.

Comment: You typically wouldn't let individual nodes `delete` its siblings either. Are the `Node`s owned by a linked list class? If so, `delete` the `Node`s in that class' destructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should exclude the current node from the `delete` operator, as the code is already a response to such a `delete`. Doing it again is like running in circles.

So modify your code to this:

```
~Node()
{
    Node *current = this->next; // exclude current node
    Node *previous;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
        previous->next = NULL; // avoid the delete below to propagate through list.
        delete previous;
    }
}
```

There is no need to set `previous` to `NULL`, since it will run out of scope. But it is needed to detach `previous` from its successors, so to avoid the the destructor will follow that chain again.

This code assumes that `this` is the *first* node of the list, which would be the natural thing to execute `delete` on. If for some reason you would execute `delete` on a node somewhere in the middle of a list, with the aim to discard the whole list, then you would need to repeat the above loop also for the nodes that precede the current node.

Answer (score 2):

You may not delete the current node itself because otherwise the code invokes undefined behavior.

Instead you could write

```
~Node()
{
    delete next;
}
```

And if the list is defined as a pointer to the head node then you need to write

```
delete head;
```

Here is a demonstration program

```
#include <iostream>

class Node
{
private:
    int data;
    Node *next;

public:

    explicit Node( int data, Node *next = nullptr ) : data( data ), next( next )
    {
    }

    ~Node()
    {
        std::cout << "Deleting " << data << "...\n";
        delete next;
    }
};

void push_front( Node *&head, int data )
{
    head = new Node( data, head );
}

int main()
{
    Node *head = nullptr;
    const int N = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        push_front( head, N - i );
    }

    delete head;
}
```

The program output is

```
Deleting 1...
Deleting 2...
Deleting 3...
Deleting 4...
Deleting 5...
Deleting 6...
Deleting 7...
Deleting 8...
Deleting 9...
Deleting 10...
```

Comment: Making the node destructor run a recursive loop is a very bad idea. If the linked list is long, you risk causing a stack overflow, since each iteration is pushing values onto the call stack to satisfy each call. Instead, manage the nodes in a container class that runs an iterative loop instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It is evident but in some books for beginners such approach is shown very often.